# Can JavaFX be used to create no-install applications?

Tags: jar, javafx

I am reading a book to learn `JavaFX` (self-studying) and the book says the following about deployment:

A

```
 JavaFX application can currently be packaged and deployed for execution in four
different ways:
1. As a desktop application delivered and installed using Java Web Start
2. As an applet delivered by a web browser and executed in the Java plug-in
3. As a TV application for a device that supports the JavaFX TV profile
4. As a mobile application delivered to a cell phone or other mobile device
```

I am not a professional developer however my strategy always was to create no-install softwares that you can run even from a flash drive you carry in your pocket (using .jar files).

Now, I would like to ask  if the same is possible in `JavaFX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> create no-install softwares that you can run even from a flash drive you carry in your pocket (using .jar files).

Yes, you can place your JavaFX application on a flash drive, plug the flash drive into a computer and run the JavaFX application stored on the flash drive without installing any additional software on the computer.

Place a Java Runtime Environment on the flash drive alongside your application's jar file.

Let's say the flash drive is drive X:, your app is on the root of the x drive and the Java runtime is stored in a directory /jre on the drive, then your app may be run on a Windows machine by running the following command at the command prompt.

```
x:\jre\bin\java.exe -jar x:\yourapp.jar
```

---

The book you are reading appears dated in it's information (e.g. the JavaFX TV profile was dropped years ago along with support for JavaFX 1.x).  I advise not to use JavaFX 1.x, instead learn and use [JavaFX 2.x+](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/index.html).

Comment: Oh ! Thanks for letting me know. I am reading [this book](http://www.amazon.com/JavaFX-Developers-Guide-Kim-Topley/dp/0321601653/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1380797113&sr=1-1&keywords=javafx+developers+guide) Can you please tell me, by looking at the table of contents, how much of it is outdated ?

Comment: Unfortunately that version of the JavaFX Developer Guide is obsolete as it is based on [JavaFX 1.x, which is End of Life](https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/javafx_1_2_and_javafx).  The runtime for the JavaFX Script language on which it was based is no longer distributed.  JavaFX Script was replaced with a new and different Java API for JavaFX 2.x.  Some basic concepts such as the SceneGraph remain the same, but many things are quite different.  That is why using JavaFX 2.x as a minimum is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle documentation details the different modes of deployment of javafx http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm